# Unable to "get around" the operating system check in an imported Python module

Tags: unit-testing, python-2.7, mocking, cross-platform

I am trying to write unit tests for a Python application and I want to write a unit test to verify that the entries in a dictionary are correct (based on the OS).

PROBLEM: I cannot mock the os that I am on. I just want to mock the os so that I can verify that the entries of a dictionary are valid. I have tried monkey patching, mocking and a patch but nothing works at the moment (which I do not doubt is due to my limited knowledge of unit-testing). The current code that I have is below. Any (detailed) help as to why this is not working or what I am doing wrong/should be doing instead will be greatly appreciated! :D

So I have:

**package.subpackage.module (mymodule.py)**

```
import sys

if platform.system() == 'Linux':
    mydictionary = {"1":one, "2":two, "3":three}

elif platform.system() == 'other_os':
    mydictionary = {"A":aaa, "B":bee, "c":cee}
```

I created a unit test here with the following code:

**package.subfolder.subsubfolder.module (myunittestmodule.py)**

```
def test_dictionary():
    import sys
    sys.modules['platform'] = Mock()
    import platform
    targetPlatform = platform
    targetPlatform.system = Mock(return_value="other_os")

    from package.subpackage.module import mydictionary
    for entry in mydictionary:
        print(entry) 
        # for now I use print to see if this even works 
        # but it only returns the dictionary for my os (linux), not anything else :(
```